# Javascript add elements to an object from another object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one object.  The first element inside the `data` object looks like this:

```
data[0] = {name:"Bob", model:"Tesla", color:"white"};
```

and a second object, whose first element looks like this:

```
new_data[0] = {salary:"50000", age:"34"};
```

`data` and `new_data` are the same length, and each element inside of the `new_data` object needs to be appended onto the correlating `data` object, to make something like this:

```
data[0] = {name:"Bob", model:"Tesla", color:"white", salary:"50000", age:"34"};
```

I've used `concat` before to add elements into a single line object ( var

```
people = ["Dan","Bob"];
people.concat("Mike");
```

, but that same idea doesn't work here:

```
for ( var i = 0;i<data.length; i++ ) {
   data[i] = data[i].concat(new_data[i]);
}
```

How do I go about looping through this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As such you have tagged your question with jQuery, I've used its `$.extend()` method below ([jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#deeptargetobject1objectN)).

This is just a one liner solution for your case. By passing `true` to this method, you can easily merge object2 into object1, recursively. jQuery is smart to figure out that both of your objects are array of same length, so the output is an array and each item in the resulting array is a merged result from both objects.

`Object.assign` is quite new (ES6) and may not be supported in all browsers ([Source](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.assign)). But this jQuery way can be a useful time saver for supporting all the browsers.

```js
var collection1 = [{
    name: "Bob",
    model: "Tesla",
    color: "white"
  },
  {
    name: "Bob 1",
    model: "Tesla 1",
    color: "white 1"
  }
];
var collection2 = [{
    salary: "50000",
    age: "34"
  },
  {
    salary: "50001",
    age: "35"
  }
];

var result = $.extend(true, collection1, collection2);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

The [**Object.assign()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

> How do I go about looping through this?

With [**Object.assign()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) in mind we can loop through it like below:

```js
var data = [];
data[0] = {name:"Bob", model:"Tesla", color:"white"};
data[1] = {name:"Martin", model:"Ford", color:"Blue"};
data[2] = {name:"Danny", model:"BMW", color:"Purple"};

var new_data =[];
new_data[0] = {salary:"50000", age:"34"};
new_data[1] = {salary:"45000", age:"24"};
new_data[2] = {salary:"10000", age:"39"};

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){    
    data[i] = Object.assign(data[i], new_data[i]);
    console.log(data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.extend` function like shown below. It extends existing `data[i]` object with properties from `new_data[i]` object.

```
for ( var i = 0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
   jQuery.extend(data[i], new_data[i]);
}
```

Comment: You don't need a extra loop, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to loop through every element in **new_data** and apply it to **data**.

```
for(var key in new_data[0]){
  data[0][key] = new_data[0][key];
}
```

Comment: You may want to add a check, `if(newData[0].hasOwnProperty(key))` before the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use if `Object.assign` like so :

```
for ( var i = 0;i < data.length; i++ ) {
  Object.assign(data[i], new_data[i]);
}
```

This will alter the content of `data`.

`concat` is meant to be used with arrays. It will append one (or more) array(s) at the end of another.

```
let people = ["Dan","Bob"];
people.concat(["Mike"]); // people is now ["Dan", "Bob", "Mike"]
```

Comment: Just be aware that IE has no support for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the keys of one of the object to merge the two. This would work in IE9 and up as well. If you need to guard against overriding a property in your base object then you could add a quick truthy check for that key before assigning in the forEach invocation.

```js
var obj1 = {id:1, name: "bob"}
var obj2 = {dob: "2000101"};

Object
.keys(obj1)
.forEach(function(k){
  obj2[k] = obj1[k];
});

console.log(obj2);
```